# what's wrong with this vuejs "prop down" example

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am new to vuejs, when i go over its document, I can't get this sample code from its "component" section work:

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <input type="text" v-model="parentMsg">
  <br>
  <child v-bind:message="parentMsg"></child>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['message'],
  template: '<span>testing: {{ message }}</span>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#example'
})
```

my understand: the value of the model can be passed on to the message properties of the child component, a string of the same content will be shown after "testing: " as soon as I key in anything in the input textbox. It didn't happen.

I tested the code from [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vue instance of `#example` should have data `parentMsg`. Then, child and parent can use it. So, you need to add data at Vue instance.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    data: function() {
        return { parentMsg: "Hi" };
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Vue.component('child', {
            props: ['myMessage'],
            template: '<div>{{ myMessage }}</div>'
        });

        Vue.component('two-items-child', {
            props: ['firstName', 'lastName'],
            template: '<div><div>{{ firstName }}</div><div>{{ lastName }}</div></div>'
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <input id="inputParent" type="text" placeholder="parent" v-model="parentMsg">
            <br>
            <child my-message="Hi Vue."></child>
            <two-items-child v-bind="wholeObj"></two-items-child>
            <child :my-message="parentMsg"></child>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // root instance
            var vm = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    parentMsg: "first msg",
                    wholeObj: {
                        firstName: "Hong",
                        lastName: "Gil-dong"
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Check above example at [example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).
The example has data as an `object` but it is not a good way. Also check it [data must be a Function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)

Comment: I'm not good at answer.. (there are so many revision..). Also I'm new to Vue.js as you are. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ this guide is good for you

Comment: Thanks to both for the answers! One more question: how do we identify "parent" and "child" component? In this case, is the part "new Vue({...})" parent component, thus making the "Vue.component" its child since it's embedded inside the "div" tag?

Comment: No. More strictly the wrapper `div` tag is not a condition of parent. Actually every element with `new Vue({ el: 'the element selector' });` is a Vue instance. And any Vue instance inside it is a child of wrapper Vue instance.

Answer (score 0):

The parent component needs to have `parentMsg` as a data attribute, otherwise it won't be reactive.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data() {
    return {
      parentMsg: ''
    }
  }
})
```